# What is the origin of using 'x' to mean 'with', and how has it spread?

Tags: etymology, prepositions

I first came across this in horticulture, for example [Viburnum × burkwoodii](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/91671/Viburnum-x-burkwoodii/Details), to symbolise a cross between species of plants.

> 6. When you see a genus name followed by the letter "x," followed, in turn, by an epithet, this is an indication that the plant is a cross between two different plant species—a "hybrid plant."

[thespruce.com](https://www.thespruce.com/why-we-use-botanical-nomenclature-2131099)

However, I have recently seen this outside of horticulture, for example you can see *'Prismic x Gatsby'* and *'Prismic x Nuxt'* [in the footer here](https://prismic.io/docs#footer), and 'Collier Webb X Samantha Todhunter' [on the Collier Webb website](https://collierwebb.com/product-category/collier-webb-x-samantha-todhunter-design/).

The meaning here is pretty much the same as the horticultural one, as they mean a cross, association, or mix of two things. Did this start in botanical nomenclature, or is there some other root (excuse the pun)?

I'm curious as to how jargon from plant names has broadened to other sociolects.

Comment: "Collier Webb X Samantha Todhunter" is a trade name.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, but I get the impression they're using it to show collaboration which is along the same lines. Collier Webb is a manufacturer, and Samantha Todhunter is a designer.

Comment: The origin is in mathematics (see [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)), not horticulture. By the name of the operation, it should be obvious why horticulture adopted it, though.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, that's the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: Also note the way it can used in electronics i.e. 'xsistor', as well as the common usages in the names of cross-utility vehicles such as 'X-Trail' etc.

Comment: @Rattler that's a bit beyond the scope here. I'm asking about _noun x noun_ to indicate how they have been mixed together.

Comment: The key is the word *cross*, not *with*. 'X' is a shorthand for *cross* because it's written as two lines that **cross** each other. IME as an electronics engineer, the "xsistor" usage is exceedingly rare. But other usages like "railroad xing" are extremely common in daily life.

Comment: @ThePhoton also 'xmas'

Answer (score 1):

The use of "X" is simply shorthand

OED

> X (n.)
>
> I. The letter, its sound or **shape;**
>
> 1 b. The letter considered with regard to its shape: chiefly attributive and in other combinations. Hence identified with a cross. X's and O's: the game of noughts and crosses. X chair, a chair in which the underframe resembles the letter X in shape;
>
> 1545   Bibliotheca Eliotæ   Decussis..is also a fourme in any thynge representynge the letter X, whiche parted in the myddell maketh an other figure called Quincunx, V.
>
> 1861   H. Hagen Synopsis Neuroptera N. Amer. 213   An x-shaped spot.
>
> 1893   F. C. Selous Trav. S.-E. Afr. 402   I will write your name..on the paper..and you must make an ‘x’ behind your name.
>
> 1976   Country Life 27 May (Suppl.) 486/1   Late 18th century wheel-back armchairs with saddle seats and X-frame legs.

**Thus  Viburnum × burkwoodii, = A cross between Viburnum and burkwoodii.**

Where cross (OED) =

> 28.a. An intermixture of breeds or races in the production of an animal; a**n instance of cross-fertilization in plants.**
>
> 1766   T. Pennant Brit. Zool. i. 8   Improved by a cross with the foreign kind.
>
> b. An animal or plant, or a breed or race, due to crossing.
>
> 1761   Philos. Trans. 1760 (Royal Soc.) 51 834   The bird..is an accidental cross, as we sportsmen term it, between a pheasant and turkey.

Comment: Don't forget that it can also mean "by" -- "south x southwest" is read as "south by southwest".

Comment: I suppose that is an extension of the idea of crossing something woth something: "south crossed with southwest."